# How do I make a custom form post to an external URL?

Tags: forms

In Drupal 8, I want a form to post to another page, but when I change the action on `$form['#action']` to a URL that makes it post there, it skips the validation.

I need the code for posting to an external URL in a submission handler.

I tried this but it gives an error.

```
$response = new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://google.com');
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: So you don't want to send an e-mail at all? If true, then `contact forms` is not what you should use.

Comment: I have to use them because of other reasons

Comment: If you want to keep validation, and hence the form, why change the post target? Wouldn't a redirect destination suffice?

Comment: well but a redirect doesnt receive the post values , does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can post your information using the Drupal HTTP client (Guzzle):

```
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$request = $client->post($url, $post_data);
$response = json_decode($request->getBody());
```

Where $url is the URL you want to post to, and $post_data is an array containing the data you want to post, in key => value format. You can build the key values in the submit handler of your form, getting the submitted values from $form_state.

You can read more about it here: https://drupalize.me/blog/201512/speak-http-drupal-httpclient

You can build your post data something like this:

```
$post_data = [
  'field1' => $form_state->getValue('field1'),
  'field2' => $form_state->getValue('field2'),
  ...
]:
```

Comment: thanks is there an example of the code to build the array for $post_data from the $form_state somewhere ?

Comment: I edited my post with more info.

Comment: I get this guzzle error : GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection() (line 187 of C:\drupalwebsite\drupal-wcms-migration\docroot\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php).

Comment: The server you are contacting is using a self-signed certificate. This means they have SSL, but not one they've paid for, so it's considered 'untrusted'. You can try disabling certification validation with `$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false)`, and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
    $post_data = $form_state->cleanValues()->getValues();
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    'form_params' => $post_data,
    'verify'=>false,
  ]);
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $status = $response->getStatusCode();
    dsm($body);
    dsm($status);
```